# If $f: I \to X$ is a path and $c: I \to X$ the constant path $c(s)=f(1)$, how is $f \cdot c$ a reparametrization of $f$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, algebraic-topology, definition

From Algebraic Topology by Hatcher:

> Definition of reparametrization:
>
> [image]

---

---

> Paragraph in question:
>
> [image]

---

If a reparametrization is defined to be a composition $f \varphi$ where $\varphi: I \to I$ satisfies $\varphi(0)=0$ and $\varphi(1)=1$, how is $f\cdot c$ a reparametrization if $c$ does not satisfy the definition?

Comment: Here $f\cdot c$ is multiplication *of paths*, so it means follow path $f$ for half the interval, then follow path $c$ for the other half (which just sits still). It’s a reparameterization by the function $\phi$ whose graph is on the left there.

Comment: f$\cdot$c is a reparamterization if there exists $\phi$ such that (f$\cdot$c)$\phi$ is a continuous map such that $\phi$(0)=0 and $\phi$(1)=1.

Comment: @JoelPereira That is not what the definition is saying. According to the definition, what you have there, $(f\cdot c)\phi$, is a reparametrization of $f\cdot c$. We want a reparametrization of $f$.

Comment: @csprun How is that a reparametrization according to the definition given?

Answer (score 1):

$f\cdot c(t)= \begin{cases} 
      f(2t) & 0\le t\le 1/2 \\
      c(2t-1) & 1/2\le t\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

so in fact

$f\cdot c(t)= \begin{cases} 
      f(2t) & 0\le t\le 1/2 \\
      f(1) & 1/2\le t\le 1 
   \end{cases}$

And since

$\phi(t)= \begin{cases} 
      2t & 0\le t\le 1/2 \\
      1 & 1/2\le t\le 1 
   \end{cases}$,

a simple calculation gives $\phi\circ f=c\cdot f,\ $ as desired.

The other case is done in exactly the same way.